# Yii CDbCriteria get all records with same character in column

Tags: yii

i'm not good with sql, i'm making a CListView for all records with a selected id in column to be displayed on the page.. just for practice, i wanted to add a dropdown that will select another kind of sort (id DESC is already there).

i have a table with columns: id, Name, Project_id, User_id, Assigned, etc...

for now this is my code:

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
            'order'=>'id desc',
            'condition'=>'Project_id='.$id
        ));

        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Task', array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria
        ));

        $this->layout = 'column2';

        $this->render('view', array('model'=>$model, 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
    }
```

i'm selecting all records that has the requested project_id, so what i'm trying to do, which i have no clue how to do, is to add another criteria selection on the column "Assigned" the problem is, some of this records has more than 1 single assigned and its being saved as "1,2,5,6". so if i add another selection with assigned 1, it will just show me thoses records that have in assigned "1" and not thoses that have "1,3,5,6".. i was thinking on make a search on string but i dont know how it works on sql (Because i dont know SQL that much)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
    'order'=>'id desc',
    'condition'=>'Project_id='.$id.' AND find_in_set($assigned, Project_id)'
));
```

But here `$assigned` can have only single value i.e. `$assigned = 1` or `$assigned = 2`.

If `$assigned = "1,2"` where `1,2` itself will be considered as single value and so result will be returned only if the pattern is `1,2..` in the table and not `2,1,...`

I hope it gives some idea.

Comment: when i add the `find_in_set()` it gives me error, i tried with `find_in_set(1, Project_id)` how would i really do this?

Comment: I have used `find_in_set()` in the same way in Yii and it works fine. Can you please mention here as what was the error your encountered. It would be easy to find a solution accordingly.

Comment: it gives me this error CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: CDbCommand failed to prepare the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: find_in_set. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'task' 't' WHERE Project_id=1 AND find_in_set(1, Assigned)

Answer (score 0):

found my solution.. seems like im using SQLite and SQLite does not support `find_in_set()`, instead. i would have to use (',' || Assigned || ',') LIKE '%,1,%'. like this..

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
            'order'=>'id desc',
            'condition'=>'Project_id='.$id.' AND ("," || Assigned || ",") LIKE "%,5,%"'
        ));
```